# How do I maintain expandable cardview visible state using viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, viewmodel, android-cardview

I am trying to maintain my expandable cardview to remain open when the apps configuration changes (e.g. screen orientation) using the viewmodel architecture. I have done zero progress regarding this.

The following code is the logic for opening and closing the cardview

```
binding.expandMoreButton.setOnClickListener {
    if (binding.collapsableItemSection.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.cardView, AutoTransition())
        }
        binding.collapsableItemSection.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.expandMoreButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_more)
        println(binding.collapsableItemSection.visibility == View.GONE)
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.cardView, AutoTransition())
        }
        binding.collapsableItemSection.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.expandMoreButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_less)
        }
    }
```

How should I implement the above logic into the viewmodel so that the expanded cardview is not closed when the screen orientation is changed to landscape or vice versa?

I tried to implement the logic into the viewmodel class using the backing properties and mutablelive data but couldn't come up with a solution.

```
private val _isExpanded = MutableLiveData(false)
    val isExpanded : LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isExpanded

    fun toggleCard(value: Boolean) {
        _isExpanded.value = value
        Log.d("HomeFragment", "Is Card Expanded : ${_isExpanded.value}")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Now your View needs to use the ViewModel as the source of truth.

So, instead of checking the current state of the view, it just depends on the state of the ViewModel:

```
viewModel.isExpanded.observe(...) { isExpanded ->
    if (!isExpanded) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.cardView, AutoTransition())
        }
        binding.collapsableItemSection.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.expandMoreButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_more)
        println(binding.collapsableItemSection.visibility == View.GONE)
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.cardView, AutoTransition())
        }
        binding.collapsableItemSection.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.expandMoreButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_less)
    }
}
```

And instead of toggling the visibility of the view, it toggles the state in the ViewModel:

```
// No need to pass a boolean to toggleCard - the ViewModel should toggle this internally
// This in turn triggers the callbackback above to update the view state
binding.expandMoreButton.setOnClickListener { viewModel.toggleCard() }
```

**UPDATE**

> the card view is inside a recyclerview, all the items of the recyclerview gets expanded when I only click on one item. Is there any kind of fix for that behavior?

Well, that wasn't clear from your original question. It does complicate things a bit :) But the concepts are the same.

ViewModel stores the view state. This time instead of a single bool, maybe a list of them:

```
// ViewModel

// ListItemState is some data class with "isExpanded" flag and other data for each item in the recyclerview
val listItemStates = MutableLiveDate<List<ListItemState>>()

fun toggleItemExpanded(position: Int) {
    // toggle expanded flag on item at position and update listItemStates
}
```

Your fragment / activity observes this state and then passes the changes to the recyclerview adapter:

```
// Fragment / Activity

viewModel.listItemStates.observe(...) { states ->
    adapter.submitList(states) // Assumes you're using ListAdapter
}

// Also listen for click events to toggle an item (you define this method)
adapter.setItemClickListener { position ->
    viewModel.toggleItemExpanded(position)
}
```

Now the adapter will have the data it needs to render the correct states:

```
// Adapter
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder : YourViewHolder position : Int) {
    val listItemState = getItem(position)
    // Now set item view state with listItemState.isExpanded

    // Set button click listener to notify fragment / activity that this item should toggle
```

}

Comment: I dont really know what observe does. what do I need to pass in parameter for the observe function and what should my toggleCard function be? 
is it like this 
`fun toggleCard() { _isExpanded.value = !_isExpanded.value!!  }`

Comment: I made it working by passing the owner through constructor and all but now since the card view is inside a recyclerview, all the items of the recyclerview gets expanded when I only click on one item. Is there any kind of fix for that behavior?

Comment: I do have a data class, but I also use the class as an entity for the ROOM DB. Should I add the isExpanded flag to the same data class?

Comment: I would not. Keep your concerns separate. Your current class is an entity for the Database. What we're discussing is a representation of view state. Your DB entity does not care about being expanded or not.

Comment: so if I do create a new data class (suppose A) with the isExpanded flag and store the room data into the class (A) wont it be redundant?

Comment: `data class ListItemState(var isExpanded: Boolean, val model: ItemDomainModel)` - nothing redundant about that. It's composition. It provides a place to add more view-related state fields as your requirements change or grow while maintaining a separation of concerns.

Comment: sorry for asking a lot but I tried the above method by creating the ListItemStates and using it in the adapter class. The problem I ran into was I wasn't able to call my order viewModel methods in the fragment class after I change the <T> of ListAdapter to the ListItemStates.

Comment: That's not enough information for me to know what is happening. If you're stuck on a new issue you best option is to ask a new specific question with enough information for someone to help you.

Comment: I wasn't able to implement your updated solution. How feasible is it to complete this task just by adding the isExpanded flag in the data class that is used for the room db. and will it help in retaining the expanded state that way?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from doing that. It'll work either way. At the end of the day, all that matters is that you keep the current expanded state _somewhere_. If you want to mix that with your DB entity, I don't think that will scale well, but it's your code. Good luck!